# Chart.js & Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3

Chart is compatible with Vue.js, although when I am fetching the api data from remote server via Fetch Api, Chart is recieving the data but not displaying it on window.

I have a template for fetching the data with default

```
<template>
    <Bar id="my-chart-id" :options="chartOptions" :data="chartData" />
</template>

<script>

import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'
import myToken from '../server/token'
import apiDataFetch from '../src/function/fetch'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

export default {
    name: 'BarChart',
    components: { Bar },
    data() {
        return {
            items: [],
            query: 'year',
            type: 'closed_category',
            chartData: {
                labels: [],
                datasets: [{ data: [] }]
            },
            chartOptions: {
                responsive: true
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getData() {
            const options = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${myToken}`,
                    'Content-Language': 'en',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }

            await apiDataFetch(`/admin/statistics/subscription?type=${this.query}`, options)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => {
                    let data = res.data.details
                    let dataset = this.chartData.datasets[0]

                    const chData = []

                    data.forEach(item => {
                        this.chartData.labels.push(item.dates.start)

                        this.items.push(item.items)
                    })


                    this.items.forEach(item => {
                        item.forEach(e => {
                            if (e.type === this.type) {
                                chData.push(e.count)
                            }
                        })
                    })
                    
                    dataset.data = [...chData]
                    console.log(dataset.data)
                })
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getData()
    },
}

</script>
```

I have seen the chart components in dev tools and here is the data is shown, but not displayed in window.

[![Here is the screenshot, sorry I could not find how to post the image normally]https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBV8G.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBV8G.png)